# How can I make a scrolling div take up less than 100% of its parent?

Tags: html, css

I feel like this should be a really simple problem, but I can't seem to figure it out.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <!-- lots of text -->
  </div>
  <div class="inner-bottom">
    This text should be inside the blue background
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
  height: 300px;
  background: #99EEFF;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.inner-bottom {
  text-align: center
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mg1de2eg/)

The goal is to have both inner divs display inside their parent, which has a background specified to visually organize them.

If I don't specify `height: 100%;` on `.inner`, it overflows, no matter which I set on the `display` property. In fact, some values of `display` even cause `height: 100%` to not work.

Anyway, I'd really like `.inner`'s size to be dictated by `.outer`'s size, rather than vice versa. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `Flexbox` just use `flex: 1` on `.inner`

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.outer {
  height: 300px;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  background: #99EEFF;
}
.inner {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.inner-bottom {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis fugiat nulla asperiores rerum sed dignissimos vitae odit consectetur perferendis! Suscipit qui hic iste est tempora blanditiis odit distinctio odio quas amet. Fuga mollitia maxime labore non odio laborum ea facilis distinctio blanditiis exercitationem atque et, facere illo repellat praesentium inventore iure. Minus error expedita veritatis doloribus esse, at cum molestias odit saepe animi harum similique, dolore distinctio est a quidem beatae! Aliquam, similique autem ipsa vitae eligendi iure consectetur. Quasi, odio expedita consequatur, maxime, libero maiores incidunt quia debitis hic provident cum, deleniti? Illo id pariatur, recusandae tenetur! Beatae cum, fuga! Nulla animi deserunt molestiae eum quia dolorum necessitatibus quod eos saepe sint eaque id est cupiditate impedit, doloribus consequuntur ipsum maiores consequatur alias. Magnam accusantium ab quia laudantium iste eum nobis sequi error, atque suscipit repellendus officiis laboriosam alias eos ullam. At inventore quam ullam officia sequi, aliquam. Aperiam dicta eum illo tempora, quas doloribus ducimus sequi placeat, aut id quaerat iure officiis nostrum accusamus atque odio repudiandae saepe autem distinctio. Qui expedita cum animi totam maxime minima labore vitae reprehenderit eligendi porro odio, voluptatem obcaecati sint enim, velit dolores, dolore fugit incidunt sit. Doloremque suscipit, quia libero. Odit nihil beatae eaque suscipit aperiam hic tempore ipsam non quam doloremque, nesciunt voluptate laboriosam a animi assumenda iste velit sunt cumque minima. Quos perferendis, labore. Consectetur quod sequi commodi nesciunt suscipit, molestiae, quia est cum. Beatae nulla, suscipit ducimus nobis voluptas illum enim dicta distinctio similique aliquam sapiente impedit ea non corrupti omnis est obcaecati labore laboriosam quaerat tempora molestias sunt laudantium doloremque? Perspiciatis dolore, excepturi, voluptate nulla nam culpa nostrum dolor, rerum quas iure dolorem incidunt consequatur dolores dolorum laborum ipsam eaque quasi accusamus voluptatum voluptates quisquam. Perspiciatis maxime, assumenda itaque eligendi dolore iste libero debitis ea sint expedita eius illum blanditiis inventore officiis voluptates minima iusto fuga nulla veritatis quo deserunt ad quisquam. Cumque numquam nihil tenetur itaque obcaecati soluta, libero possimus dolore ipsa eum neque amet sunt ad sapiente quos quae deleniti voluptas illo molestiae. Nihil officiis, commodi fugiat architecto blanditiis! Atque neque numquam nobis voluptates accusantium libero tempore veniam fugit officiis alias soluta rem enim, totam aut eos, nam. Fuga labore fugiat, suscipit consequatur ipsum quia praesentium. Reprehenderit praesentium maxime, ea maiores repellat, facere architecto quasi vitae a hic similique impedit commodi dolor, quas necessitatibus saepe ipsum. Nulla distinctio corporis dolor praesentium eum laudantium, asperiores magni minus tempora, iusto veritatis fuga. Totam ratione incidunt, neque blanditiis iure corporis consectetur ea dignissimos nesciunt tenetur ab placeat, harum eaque laboriosam numquam quas ipsum! Earum aperiam, voluptatibus assumenda quisquam dolorem ut eius non provident numquam nostrum rerum, magnam voluptatum beatae quibusdam quasi ad consequuntur perspiciatis fugiat soluta ipsa excepturi! Earum, accusamus quidem! Quos, eaque inventore perferendis quia officiis tempore sequi repellendus incidunt quo, numquam aut mollitia, atque earum architecto. Harum ipsa debitis necessitatibus quos sapiente ad deleniti quod non nihil libero iure voluptatem, omnis possimus tempore eos recusandae! Provident modi nulla dicta, aut possimus dolores nesciunt officiis sunt! Sunt!
  </div>
  <div class="inner-bottom">
    This text should be inside the blue background
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without flexbox? I'd ideally like this compatible with IE8 and 9

Comment: Does `inner-bottom` have fixed height?

Comment: Well, I'm searching for as conceptually pure of a solution as possible; I could give it a fixed height, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: I think if you are already giving a fixed height to the outer div than you are already taking control of the element height wise. There's no reason not to take more control of the inner elements. What do you mean by "conceptually pure"?

Comment: I think OP wants `inner-bottom` height to be flexible and `inner` to take rest of height of 300px that is left, but other then flexbox i am not sure this is possible with pure css.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of. In the actual problem I'm attempting to solve, the outer div doesn't have a fixed height; I just gave it one for the purposes of reproducing the issue. "Conceptually pure" might not be the right phrase for the idea I have, but basically I'd ideally like a cross-compatible solution without magic numbers, fixed sizing, padding/margin hacks, etc. I know that's asking a lot, though...

Comment: I just think we are working with an incomplete puzzle here. So in the actual problem, you want to create a div with scrolling text inside another div. However you don't want to give a fixed height to either div. The browser needs some type of cutoff to know when to cap the inner div and start scrolling. Where is that information going to come from? From the viewport? From the height of the content container? You gotta throw it a bone somehow. Maybe if we had more info about the project we could help more.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of the inner element , that is the best way

```
.inner {
    height: 275px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Use a padding bottom to the parent element, that is 'outer' class.

```
.outer {
    height: 300px;
    background: #99EEFF;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I mean.......*technically* that works, but it's definitely a hack. I don't want the `inner-bottom` `div` inside the padding of the `outer` div. I want it laid out inside the div. In other words, if I specify padding on the `outer` div, it should affect `inner-bottom`

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is the way to go here, but if you want a non-flex answer: If you are assigning 300px to the outer div then you can assign fixed pixel values to the inner divs. how big do you want them to be? You can do:

```
.inner {
 height: calc(100% - (insert height of .inner-bottom));
}
```

Or you can just use percentages that add up to 100 for the height of both elements. Or you can just use pixels that add up to 300. Your call.

Answer (score 0):

The text in the `inner-bottom` is out of the blue background, because the `.inner` div **takes up all available height** in the `.outer` DIV. 
If you set the height of the `.inner` DIV to less than 100%, there will still be some space for the `.inner-bottom` to fit in the `.outer` DIV. 
So, changing

```
height: 100%
```

to for example

```
height:65%
```

in the `.inner` should work.

PS. You can change the 65% to any value less than 100% and it should still work properly.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out a simpler, more dynamic, and more cross-compatible approach using tables.

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="tr greedy">
    <div class="td">
      <div class="scrollable">
        <!-- Lots of text -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td centered">
      Text should be inside the blue box
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
  display: table;
  height: 300px;
  background: #99EEFF;
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
}

.td {
  display: table-cell;
}

.scrollable {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.greedy {
  height: 100%;
}

.centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I personally think this is a very unnecessary and overly complicated approach. But to each his own.